# Is this Vulkan validation error message normal?

Tags: vulkan

When I create an image for the first time in Vulkan it's in the UNDEFINED layout. I want to do a buffer to image copy so I transition the image to transfer destination source first.

```
VkImageMemoryBarrier image_barrier;
image_barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
image_barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
image_barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
image_barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
image_barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
image_barrier.pNext = nullptr;
image_barrier.srcAccessMask = 0; 
image_barrier.dstAccessMask = 0;
image_barrier.image = image.vulkan_image->vk_image_handle;
image_barrier.subresourceRange = subresource_range;




/* IMAGE IS TRANSITIONED TO TRANSFER DESTINATION OPTIMAL */
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmd_buffer->vk_buffer_handle,
VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT,
0,
0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &image_barrier);
```

Now I do a vkCmdCopyBufferToImage. In the image barrier I use VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT, so the image transition from undefined to transfer destination source should be complete BEFORE the copy buffer to image command is started. However I get this error in the validation layer:

> vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(): Layout for VkImage 0x45a74f000000004a[] is
> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL but can only be
> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL. The
> Vulkan spec states: dstImageLayout must be
> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL

I'm not sure why it says it's in the SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL layout, as the image has just been created and it should be in the UNDEFINED layout. However disregarding that, is it normal for this error warning to fire given that technically, because I haven't submitted the command buffer yet, I've merely pushed the command to do the layout transition, that the Vulkan doesn't know that the image, by the time it starts the copy buffer to image command, will be in the proper transfer destination layout?

Is this a sort a message that should be suppressed or ignored?

Comment: No, that message should not be ignored. It's an error and a strict implementation may fail your copy command. But to help you on this we'd need the whole relevant part of your code.

Comment: @SaschaWillems The thing is, I create an image with UNDEFINED layout. I issue a command to do an image transition to TRANSFER_SOURCE. I do a copy command, and the validation layer tells me it's not in TRANSFER_SOURCE layout, but how does it know? I haven't submitted the command buffer, just issued the transition to TRANSFER_SOURCE. The last that Vulkan saw of the image was probably at image creation, which was UNDEFINED. That is of course unless the validation layers keep track of the image barrier and the transition, then it would know.

Comment: @Zebrafish "probably"? Yes, the validation keeps track of the barriers; that's it's job...

Comment: PS: no error by the validation layers is designed to be suppressed. Which sounds self-obvious to me (error is error, after all, and nobody in their right mind wants to have any errors), so as such I would not find this question useful to future readers. Otherwise if this is debugging help, we ideally need full verifiable timeline of the image. `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` and debug markers might be useful to exhaustively track all uses of the image.